# copy column values if column name is a date

Tags: java, sqlite, copy

I am trying to copy all values from one table to another table. I am using SQlite. I have multiple columns with the following column names - name,accounts,email, 12/30/2016,01/13/2017.... All columns are named as dates except for the first 3 columns. I am trying to copy using this statement:

```
    PreparedStatement prepCopy = con
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1(12/30/2016) SELECT 12/30/2016 FROM table2");
    prepCopy.execute();
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 near "12": syntax error:
```

I tried doing this for the other columns like name, accounts, and email and it works. This error only occurs on the date column names. I also tried putting '' before and after the date but then it populates all rows with the date itself. I think I am missing a small detail, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any suggestion is appreciated. :)

Comment: You should test your sql statement on SQL query first

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. But it's giving me an error. I also tried doing '12/30/2016' but it inserts the value 12/30/2016 on all rows of the column named 12/30/2016 on the new table. when i try it on the columns name, accounts, and email, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the dates - in those cases in which they are column names - with double quotes or backticks.

```
INSERT INTO table1("12/30/2016") SELECT "12/30/2016" FROM table2
```

See also: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html